# how to correct nginx conf with strapi

Tags: strapi

what's the problem of this `nginx.conf`?
I had to change somewhere but still not working ..

```
upstream strapi {
    server localhost:1337   max_fails=1 fail_timeout=5s;
}
server {

# Listen HTTP
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name sh**rk.app;

# Proxy Config
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @strapi;
    }

    location @strapi{
        proxy_pass http://strapi;
    }

}
```

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: I had finish setup strapi dev ,while open via 1337, it runs ok. but while through nginx proxy. it just show up the front page but no the http://sh**rk.app/admin.

Comment: I mean,, please help for correct the nginx error for strapi frontend and backend. thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok you can configure with this way that is a good way
[deploy strapi on ubuntu server](https://medium.com/strapi/how-to-deploy-a-strapi-api-on-ubuntu-16-04-17f8fbbf5c5b)

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I had fix my problem by add " proxy_temp_path  /var/nginx/proxy_temp; " and make this folder in nobody:nogroup .

Comment: as before, I was using a nginx by wget and configure , not the one base on ubuntu setup.  while I configure it , I put it in the /root/ ,that makes the client read permission complexity. aha

Comment: Hackemate, would you be willing to summarise the linked article in your answer? Presently it is what we call a "link only answer", which is not substantive enough for Stack Overflow.